# Decide whether the following $f:\textbf{R}^{n}\to\textbf{R}^{m}$ function is a linear mapping or not

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Decide whether the following function $f:\textbf{R}^{n}\to\textbf{R}^{m}$ is a linear mapping or not.

If the answer is yes, then determine the matrix of the mapping $[f]$, the kernel $\ker(f)$ and the image $\text{Im}(f)$ and the dimensions of the latter two, where $f:\textbf{R}^{3}\to\textbf{R}^{2}$, $f(x, y, z) =
(x − y + z, x − y + z)$.

I have find out that the mapping is linear (by two properties). However I could not go further.

Answer (score 0):

In order to express the matricial representation of $f$, we need to choose a basis for $\textbf{R}^{3}$ as well as for $\textbf{R}^{2}$.

Let us consider $\mathcal{B} = \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ and $\mathcal{B}' = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ to be such bases.

Then we can express $[f]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'}$ as follows
\begin{align*}
[f]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'} & = [f((1,0,0))_{\mathcal{B}'},f((0,1,0))_{\mathcal{B}'},f((0,0,1))_{\mathcal{B}'}] =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Since $\text{Im}(f) = \text{span}\{f(1,0,0),f(0,1,0),f(0,0,1)\} = \text{span}\{(1,1)\}$, we conclude that $\dim\text{Im}(f) = 1$ and $\dim\ker(f) = 2$ due to the rank-nullity theorem.

As to the kernel, we have the following equation to solve
\begin{align*}
f(x,y,z) = (0,0) & \Longleftrightarrow x - y + z = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z = y - x\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x,y,z) = (a,b,b-a)
\end{align*}

where $a,b\in\textbf{R}$. Hence $\ker(f) = \text{span}\{(1,0,-1),(0,1,1)\}$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I didnt understand why  $\text{Im}(f) = \text{span}\{f(1,0,0),f(0,1,0),f(0,0,1)\} = \text{span}\{(1,1)\}$

Comment: That's because $f(1,0,0) = -f(0,1,0) = f(0,0,1) = (1,1)$.

Comment: More generally, given a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{b_{1},b_{2},\ldots,b_{n}\}$ of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and a linear transformation $T:V\to W$, the following relation holds:

$$\text{Im}(T) = \text{span}\{T(\mathcal{B})\}$$

Answer (score 0):

For the matrix try to evaluate on the Canonical basis of $R^3$ and try to write each result as a linear combination of the Canonical basis of $R^2$

For instance $f(1, 0,0) =(1, 1) =1(1, 0) +1(0, 1) $

Thus the first column of your matrix is $(1, 1) ^T$

You do it with $(0, 1,0) $ and $(0, 0,1) $ to get the second and third column of your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $f$ is a linear mapping. Clearly, identity is mapped to identity as $f(0,0,0)=(0,0)$ 
For any two vectors $u=(x_1,y_1,z_1)^T $ and $v=(x_2,y_2,z_2)^T \in \mathbb R^3$, we have $f(u+v)=(x_1+x_2 − y_1-y_2 + z_1+z_2, x_1+x_2 − y_1-y_2 + z_1+z_2)^T=(x_1 − y_1 + z_1, x_1 − y_1 + z_1)^T+(x_1 − y_1 + z_1, x_1 − y_1 + z_1)^T=f(u)+f(v)$ 
Similarly show that for any scaler $c \in \mathbb R$, $f(cu)=cf(u)$ for all $u\in \mathbb R^3$. Hence, $f$ is a linear map.

Now for the matrix calculation:
Note that $(x,y,z)^T=xe_1+ye_2+ze_3$ where $e_i's$ are standard basis vectors. 
Hence, $f(x,y,z)^T=xf(e_1)+yf(e_2)+zf(e_3)=[f(e_1)  \;\;f(e_2)\;\;\;f(e_3)](x,y,z)^T=A(x,y,z)^T$ 
where, $A=[f(e_1)  \;\;f(e_2)\;\;\;f(e_3)]$, a $(2 \times 3 )$ matrix.

Ker(f)= Null space of $A$, 
Im(f)= Column space  $A$